# MARS not working with sql native client

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc

I have a C# application that export data to sql server using odbc connection. I got this error:

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): 
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]
Connection is busy with results for another command.
```

I have tried `MARS_Connection=yes` in the connection string but it is not working.There is no problem with sql native client 10 but the problem comes with sql native client(sqlncli). [I found a solution in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701992/turning-on-multiple-result-sets-in-an-odbc-connection-to-sql-server) but I don't know how to implement `SQLSetConnectAttr` and other functions to enable mars.

Comment: open a second connection for the query when iterating over results on the first connection